# Fill data into matrix, pass elements that its defined index encounter IndexError

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, matrix

For creating matrix, I have two `numpy` arrays for positioning row and column

```
row = np.array([1,5,8,15,2])
column = np.array([2,3,4,7,8])
```

The dimension of mymatrix is 10*10

```
mymatrix = np.zeros(shape=(10,10))
```

I want to fill 100 at the defined positions from row and column arrays (pairing by their indices). If the index is out of bound (such as `(row=15,column=7)`), I want to pass only that element. I used

```
try:
  mymatrix[row, column] = 100
except IndexError:
  pass
```

But this passes all the process, no element is filled into matrix. I want it to pass just IndexError element. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a mask of valid rows and columns and use it to mask them and index into the 2D array and then assign with [`integer-array indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing). Thus, with `row` and `column` as arrays, we would have one solution like so -

```
m,n = mymatrix.shape
mask = (row>=0) & (row < m) & (column>=0) & (column < n)
mymatrix[row[mask], column[mask]] = 100
```

Sample run -

```
In [19]: row = np.array([1,5,8,15,2])
    ...: column = np.array([2,3,4,7,8])
    ...: 

In [20]: mymatrix = np.zeros(shape=(10,10))

In [21]: m,n = mymatrix.shape

In [22]: mask = (row>=0) & (row < m) & (column>=0) & (column < n)

In [23]: mymatrix[row[mask], column[mask]] = 100

In [24]: (mymatrix==100).sum() # number of elements edited to 100
Out[24]: 4
```

If `row` and `column` are guaranteed to be greater than or equal to `0`, skip the `(row>=0)` and `(column>=0)` parts.

Comment: This is cool. Thanks so much. I have one problem; my mask gave all false. I checked the element of row, it is more than 0 and less than `m` (column is totally right). Do you know how to fix this?

  `mask = (index < m) & (col_num>=0) # >return all false in array`   ;    
 `print index[4] < m   # >true`   ;  
 `print mask[4]   # >false`   ;

Comment: @Jan Is `index` a list or array or a scalar? Similar what is `col_num`, an array, or list or scalar?

Comment: Oh I am sorry. `index` is `<type 'list'>`, `col_num` is `<type 'numpy.ndarray'>`. Should I just fix it by changing `index` to np.array?

Comment: @Jan Yes, please make sure both `row` and `column` are arrays.

Comment: Thanks again! May I ask a little more? In case I know my column works fine, I wonder the condition `& (column ... ` must be defined here because we want 2D? Or is there a way to ignore column at all?

Comment: @Jan If you are sure that `column` elements are fine, skip `(column>=0)`  and `(column < n)` parts from the `mask` calculation.

Answer (score 1):

Do:

```
import numpy as np

m = np.zeros((10, 10))
rows = np.array([1, 5, 8, 15, 2])
columns = np.array([2, 3, 4, 7, 8])

n, p = m.shape
for i, j in zip(rows, columns):
    if 0 <= i < n and 0 <= j < p:
        m[i, j] = 100

print(m)
```

Output:

```
[[   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.]
 [   0.    0.  100.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.]
 [   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.  100.    0.]
 [   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.]
 [   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.]
 [   0.    0.    0.  100.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.]
 [   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.]
 [   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.]
 [   0.    0.    0.    0.  100.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.]
 [   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.    0.]]
```

You can see if correct:

```
print('rows: {}, \ncolumns: {}'.format(*np.where(m == 100)))
```

Output:

```
rows: [1 2 5 8], 
columns: [2 8 3 4]
```

Performance:

**solution.py**

```
import numpy as np

m = np.zeros((10, 10))
rows = np.array([1, 5, 8, 15, 2])
cols = np.array([2, 3, 4, 7, 8]) 

# without numpy
def multiple_insert(m, value, rows, cols):
    n, p = m.shape
    for i, j in zip(rows, cols):
        if 0 <= i < n and 0 <= j < p:
            m[i, j] = value


# with numpy
def multiple_insert2(m, value, rows, cols):
    n, p = m.shape
    mask = (0 <= rows) & (rows < n) & (0 <= cols) & (cols < p)
    m[rows[mask], cols[mask]] = value
```

In `ipython` console:

```
In [1]: run solution.py

In [2]: %timeit multiple_insert(m, 100, rows, cols)
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.06 µs per loop

In [3]: %timeit multiple_insert2(m, 100, rows, cols)
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.34 µs per loop
```

Sometimes using always NumPy is bad.

Comment: That's the case with NumPy versus a loopy solution - If you are not iterating enough, you won't see performance benefits with NumPy.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies here : `mymatrix[row, column] = 100` . `row` and `column` are arrays not integers.

You need to iterate over the row and column array and pass each element in `mymatrix`.